# Should I pass ZooKeeper nodes to PyKafka's KafkaClient?

Tags: python, apache-kafka

The examples for PyKafka's KafkaClient show the Kafka nodes being passed to the client's constructor:

```
from pykafka import KafkaClient
client = KafkaClient(hosts="127.0.0.1:9092")
```

Thus, if I have multiple Kafka nodes, I could pass them all as part of the hosts kw. However, since ZooKeeper knows about all of the Kafka nodes, it seems like a better approach would be to pass the location of the ZooKeeper cluster.

What's the best practice in this case? Does PyKafka support passing ZooKeeper nodes to the client constructor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For KafkaClient, Not necessary. You can provide Comma-separated list of kafka hosts to used to connect (here:http://pykafka.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api/client.html) or KazooClient connect string (which contains zookeeper info, hosts and ports of zookeeper). From the source code of _get_metadata() function, the cluster object get the broker information from the zookeeper (if zookeeper host ips provided. here https://github.com/Parsely/pykafka/blob/1b2d030b073f276c18fd6b1a64320de58d4d7904/pykafka/cluster.py).

For other clients, such as pykafka.balancedconsumer.BalancedConsumer, you may need to provide zookeeper info (http://pykafka.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api/balancedconsumer.html).

By the way, read the doc carefully, not all functionalities in java client or defined in protocols are implemented in python clients now.

Comment: Thanks! I've seen that doc before (and, maybe my question wasn't clear), and it seems like it would be nice if zookeeper was consulted for this information rather than duplicating it within code or config files. Is this concern unfounded? How is PyKafka generally used in production when establishing connections?

Comment: @matthewatabet I remember that there are zookeeper information in kafka config file. So, I think the client can handle this. It depends on your need and the client you select. By the way, I used https://github.com/dpkp/kafka-python. and read the doc carefully, not all functionalities in java client are implemented in python client.

Comment: @matthewatabet Before selecting clients and lib(s), read the doc carefully and think about whether the lib can support what you need or not. for example, group, distribution algorithms inside group, and so on.

Comment: thanks! in this case, the client was selected before i joined the project and the docs for pykafka weren't that clear. i tried passing the zookeeper address in as part of the hosts list, and got some warnings back.

Comment: @matthewatabet How did you pass the zookeeper address in as part of the hosts list?

Comment: @matthewatabet I guess the hosts to KafkaClient should be kafka nodes, or(not and) zookeeper nodes. Try it.

Comment: yes, it should indeed be kafka nodes. the reason is that the kafka nodes are aware of the entire cluster and will redirect producer messages to the leader. So, Zookeeper is actually only needed in the consumer case. Which is why zk nodes aren't mentioned when instantiating the kafka client.

Comment: @matthewatabet You can pass zookeeper nodes to KafkaClient, from the source code here (https://github.com/Parsely/pykafka/blob/1b2d030b073f276c18fd6b1a64320de58d4d7904/pykafka/cluster.py), I did not try.... The zookeeper is used to get the broker nodes. so, I guess, passing zookeeper nodes is not necessary.

Comment: yeah, it looks like it is possible to pass ZK nodes as the host list. But, it seems inefficient (both when reading the code and when executing a test producer). Seems like the producer will try several times to talk to the ZK nodes as if they were Kafka nodes and then only try a ZK connection once all attempts fail. When running tests, this seemed to take 2-5 seconds. I assume there are settings to adjust retries etc; I'd prefer an explicit zk_hosts keyword.

Answer (score 0):

To clarify the discussion here a bit: since [this pull request](https://github.com/Parsely/pykafka/pull/432), PyKafka has supported `zookeeper_hosts` as a kwarg on `KafkaClient`. This allows users to specify either zookeeper or kafka nodes when instantiating a client - `zookeeper_hosts` takes precedence over `hosts` when specified. This is provided only as a convenience, though - knowledge of the zookeeper hosts is not strictly necessary in any PyKafka component other than the `BalancedConsumer`. When used during `KafkaClient` instantiation, `zookeeper_hosts` is simply used to automatically discover the hostnames of the Kafka brokers.